# Bash script case does not evaluate conditions right

Tags: bash, jenkins, build-automation

I am executing this shell script in a Jenkins job. 
The idea here to run the next step of the job only if the condition in this script is evaluated to true.
If the build number has word SNAPSHOT in it, it should evaluate to true and perform the next step.

```
#!/bin/sh
snapshot_present=true
v="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
case $v in
    *SNAPSHOT*)
        echo "snapshot ${v} being pushed to prod";;
    *)
        echo "no match found in ${v}"
esac
exit
```

However, when I run this job. The output I get is:

> no match found in 77

77 is the build number here.
And the job continues to execute the next step irrespectively.

Is my condition getting evaluated right? If so, then why do I get the other output? Whereas it should produce

> snapshot ${v} being pushed to prod

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: `no match found in 77` is correct/expected behavior, given a `v` of `77`: If `v=77`, it doesn't contain the string `SNAPSHOT`, which is what the `case` is searching for. Why do you expect the other condition to execute? Which is to say -- why is the other condition the "right" one? You're telling us what you expect, but not why you think it's the reasonable or correct thing to expect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would I set this condition to fail and prevent Jenkins to run the next step in conditional build job?
The job executes the next step irrespective of what condition gets executed. 

How does `snapshot_present=true` make a difference? Or is the job itself configured wrong?

Comment: @ShabbirBata, if you want it to stop, put something like `exit 1` inside the relevant block. Why do you think `snapshot_present=true` is supposed to make a difference?

Comment: We can't say what's "right" or "wrong" because we aren't inside the minds of the people who configured your job, and the question of intent is something that exists only in that person's head. We can tell you what code *actually does*, but you need to be the person who knows what it's *intended* to do.

Comment: Maybe you need to put `snapshot_present=false` in the `*)` block?

Comment: @Barmar, since there's an `exit` just below, nothing is ever reading the variable's value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I suspect that's just for the example in the question. He says that it "performs the next step", what could that be if the script exits?

Comment: What do you mean by "it should evaluate to true and perform the next step"? You exit from the script immediately after the `case` statement, there is no next step to execute.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes that was my intention. To exit the script if the condition is met and perform the next step.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with your statement. And I think I have the answer I need. 
Which is listed below by John Kugelman.

Comment: The `exit` statement isn't in the `case`, so it's not dependent on whether the condition is true or false.

Comment: Is "the next step" in another script that's calling this script? Nothing you do in thie script affects how that other script runs, it will execute the next step whether the condition is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
no match found in 77
```

As the printout shows, `$v` is set to `77` and does not contain the word `SNAPSHOT`. So yes, it is correct that the `*)` case is triggered.